"Can't pickle local object" when multiprocessing in Python
I am writing a program that calls a function several times, each intended to be run simultaneously over the course of hours. It's my first attempt at multiprocessing, and it's evident from looking at other similar threads here that I need to read up on the process of "pickling". However, if I'm missing something simple here I'm hoping someone could get me past this.
The error:
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'

Excuse my language but there seems to be a problem with the forking pickler.
Here's a simplified representation of the code that has me in a pickle:
def run_runner(date, info):
    do stuff

processes = []
for t in range(len(sites)):
    process = Process(target = run_runner, args=[date, info[t]])
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()


Pickle is just serialisation and you need that to pass objects between processes. What you have listed as do stuff is probably where the problem lies because there are issues in passing objects like classes with methods, which is why you might try something like dill. There's just not enough info but I think you're focusing on the wrong things

I agree, there's no code of where/how the pickling took place. There's only the code of the thread. Please see minimal reproducible code.

thanks all - I will need to circle back and provide more code. The function runs fine on its own, so I assumed something with the multiprocessing call was causing the error.

When the lack of a [MCVE] is fixed, this will end up being a clear duplicate of AttributeError: Can't pickle local object in Multiprocessing (but I accidentally squandered my dupehammer so I can't close it myself).

@ShadowRanger I see that you're right. And I get a different set of problems after putting the process calls in a function as the duplicate shows. I'll have to take a step back and maybe create a new question. My "do stuff" calls a class method so I think that's where the issue is.

The function you pass to Process must be able to be imported by the child process. The target function and arguments are passed to the child using pickle, and while data is serialized and sent, functions and things like class definitions are only sent a reference, so the receiver must import them.
